aggregate jsonb data in Postgres
I have a jsonb field in a database table that holds the following data:
{"access": {
  "D2024.06.13": [{"qty": 1, "time": "12:05"}, {"qty": 3, "time": "12:32"}],
  "D2024.06.14": [{"qty": 1, "time": "08:37"}]
}}

I would like to group the data by date and by time in 10 min slots (00:00 to 23:50)
so
2024.06.13
12:00 : 1
12:10 : 0
12:20 : 0
12:30 : 3
12:40 : 0
...

{'2024.06.13' : {'12:00':1, '12:10':0, '12:20':0, '12:30':3, '12:40':0 ....}, '2024.06.13' : {'12:00':1 ....}

so I can draw a timeline afterwards.

In multiple steps:

create table with sample data:

create table mytable as 
( select 1 as x, '{"access": {
  "D2024.06.13": [{"qty": 1, "time": "12:05"}, {"qty": 3, "time": "12:32"}],
  "D2024.06.14": [{"qty": 1, "time": "08:37"}]
}}'::jsonb as j);


Get the number of days

with nrofDays as (
   select 
      min(substr(key,2,10)::date) as fromdate, 
      max(substr(key,2,10)::date) as todate,
      max(substr(key,2,10)::date) - min(substr(key,2,10)::date)+1 as count
   from 
      mytable, 
      jsonb_each(j->'access')
)
SELECT * FROM nrofDays




fromdate
todate
count




2024-06-13
2024-06-14
2




The select all 10-minute intervals:

with nrofDays as (
   select 
      min(substr(key,2,10)::date) as fromdate, 
      max(substr(key,2,10)::date) as todate,
      max(substr(key,2,10)::date) - min(substr(key,2,10)::date)+1 as count
   from 
      mytable, 
      jsonb_each(j->'access')
)
,timescale as (
   select ((select fromdate from nrofDays) + '00:00'::time + interval '1 minute' * t) as tim 
   from generate_series(0,(24*60*(select count from nrofDays)),10) t
)
select * from timescale




tim




2024-06-13 00:00:00.000


2024-06-13 00:10:00.000


2024-06-13 00:20:00.000


2024-06-13 00:30:00.000


2024-06-13 00:40:00.000


2024-06-13 00:50:00.000


2024-06-13 01:00:00.000


2024-06-13 01:10:00.000


...


2024-06-14 23:20:00.000


2024-06-14 23:30:00.000


2024-06-14 23:40:00.000


2024-06-14 23:50:00.000


2024-06-15 00:00:00.000




select your data, in a normalized ways (no json columns):

  select 
   x,
   substring(key,2,10)::date as dat,
   (value->>'time')::time as tim,
   substring(key,2,10)::date + (value->>'time')::time as dt 
from 
(select x, key, value as v1
    from 
        mytable, 
        jsonb_each(j->'access') 
    ) x,
    jsonb_array_elements(v1)




x
dat
tim
dt




1
2024-06-13
12:05:00
2024-06-13 12:05:00.000


1
2024-06-13
12:32:00
2024-06-13 12:32:00.000


1
2024-06-14
08:37:00
2024-06-14 08:37:00.000




Select the data from step 2, and LEFT JOIN it with the results from step 3

with nrofDays as (
   select 
      min(substr(key,2,10)::date) as fromdate, 
      max(substr(key,2,10)::date) as todate,
      max(substr(key,2,10)::date) - min(substr(key,2,10)::date)+1 as count
   from 
      mytable, 
      jsonb_each(j->'access')
)
,timescale as (
   select ((select fromdate from nrofDays) + '00:00'::time + interval '1 minute' * t) as tim 
   from generate_series(0,(24*60*(select count from nrofDays)),10) t
)
select 
   timescale.tim,
   count(x)
from timescale
left join 
   (
   select 
   x,
   substring(key,2,10)::date as dat,
   (value->>'time')::time as tim,
   substring(key,2,10)::date + (value->>'time')::time as dt 
from 
(select x, key, value as v1
    from 
        mytable, 
        jsonb_each(j->'access') 
    ) x,
    jsonb_array_elements(v1)
) d on d.dt between timescale.tim and timescale.tim + interval '1 minute' * 10 
group by timescale.tim
order by timescale.tim

MOTE: The selected days always start at '00:00', so you might need to do some tweaking when you whish them to start at '12:05' on your first day, but I leave that to you 
see: DBFIDDLE

Here is it using CTEs.
-- Illustrative data

create table raw_data (j jsonb);
insert into raw_data values
('{"access": {
  "D2024.06.13": [{"qty": 1, "time": "12:05"}, {"qty": 3, "time": "12:32"}],
  "D2024.06.14": [{"qty": 1, "time": "08:37"}]
}}'::jsonb),
('{"access": {
  "D2024.06.15": [{"qty": 1, "time": "13:05"}, {"qty": 3, "time": "13:32"}],
  "D2024.06.16": [{"qty": 1, "time": "09:37"}]
}}'::jsonb);


Flatten the JSON data (flat_data CTE)
Make a list of all time points for every raw data date (time_slots CTE)
Join them.

with flat_data as 
(
 select substr(d, 2)::date event_date, 
        (l -> 'qty')::integer qty,
        date_bin(interval 'PT10M', substr(d, 2)::date + (l ->> 'time')::time, 'epoch') event_ts
 from raw_data,
 lateral jsonb_each (raw_data.j -> 'access') as t(d, v),
 lateral jsonb_array_elements(v) l
),
days as 
(
 select distinct event_date from flat_data
),
time_slots as 
(
 select generate_series(event_date + time '00:00', event_date + time '23:55', interval 'PT10M') as time_slot
 from days
)
select  time_slot::date as event_date,
        jsonb_object_agg(time_slot::time, coalesce(qty, 0)) as events
from time_slots 
left outer join flat_data on time_slot = event_ts
group by time_slot::date
order by time_slot::date;

Demo
Unrelated but this is a bad data design for time series sensor  data.
